# Problems trying to run Docker Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: 20.04, docker

I followed the instructions on how to install Docker Desktop. When I start it. It says Docker Desktop stopped and engine not started.

The Docker Diagnostics ID is:

```
1e031030-f54a-4944-af27-d0458a8d136b/20220602004010
```

I'm not sure on how to fix it. This is a new install of ubuntu 20.04 with only docker desktop installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the dependencies on the Docker Desktop linux install pages? There are a few. Not least of which is that this only runs under gnome or KDE. Check your environment with:

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

I can't help you further. I am using XFCE so its quite probable it wont work for me. Also, I have production code running in Docker and I reallly don't want to mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem by enabling virtualization from the BIOS settings.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using Docker Desktop and just using Docker Compose instead. Maybe not as pretty, but easier.